# Sonatype Nexus - no pom files in storage or index

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, nexus

i am new to nexus and maven. I am trying to create a project in java with maven archetypes.
So I create a maven-quickstart project. Maven is connecting to my Nexus-Server and starts to download all necessary .jars and .poms. Everything with apache-maven* works fine. But for the plexus files i got the message.

[WARN] ... plexus-utils.jar:1.4.1 is missing, no dependency information available
...

When i browse remote in the nexus GUI in the central repo, i see all poms, jars, etc. files. When i browse in the repo storage or index, i only see some jars (javadoc.jar, sources.jar etc.), but no pom files.

But again for apache-maven sources i see all pom and jar files in the browse index and browse storage trees.

So any suggesstions? Where did i make a mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What groupid are you using? As you've stated there is a POM present for version 1.4.1 of that artifact:

- http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.codehaus.plexus|plexus-utils|1.4.1|jar

You need to provide details of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try starting with the suggestions here:  https://support.sonatype.com/entries/21437881-Troubleshooting-Artifact-Download-Failures

Comment: deleting the files in the .\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-utils directory worked. i also increased the timeout rate like it was suggessted in that link of yours. since then, everything worked. thanks.